# ensure that a equation can never be less than 0 - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have this calculation:

```
 10 - 12
```

I will obviously be returned -2. But I want to use a either a ruby or rails method that will basically return 0 if that calculation is passed to it. I've can't seem to figure this one out?

Comment: I am not sure about what you want. Something like this? `[10 - 12, 0].max`

Comment: Yeah actually that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this.  For example:

```
[10 - 12, 0].max
```

Or:

```
result = 10 - 12 
result < 0 ? 0 : result
```